# Has the R community overreacted to this question and answer?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, voting, upvotes

A few hours ago I found this R question and answer: *[Getting 'Error ' message when I run my for loop in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41397275/4891738)*. It was astonishing for me to find that the answer got 12 upvotes.

From the comments around there, it is clear that R community has used their upvotes to express, possibly their anger, against a user whose comment was deemed unfriendly. One highly respectable user even offered a bounty on the answer.

But, has the community over reacted?

- The question is **not reproducible** in the first place;
- **The bug in OP's code is obvious**, that he used `stop()` rather than `break`. I left a comment, also the first comment to this question (but I deleted it just now), about this simple error;
- After *Fr* posted his answer, OP admitted that it was due to his own mistake: he forgot to remove those `stop()` clause. So, it is clear that this question is **a simple typographical error**.

To me, it seems that this question should be closed, yet it got five upvotes. Well, neither the question nor the answer has the matching quality for the votes.

I also found some following-up effects:

[image]

*Fr* is getting a wave of downvotes from the community right now.

Having observed those, I begin to doubt about what is fair and what is unfair.

Comment: Tangential note: "[...] against a user whose comment was deemed unfriendly" -- It is worth it to take a moment to contemplate the absurdity of that comment. Mooting "adds nothing new compared with existing comments" as an explanation for downvotes against a well-written answer which was posted *six minutes* after the question... that feels like a new low in terms of pettiness.

Comment: This is a fantastic example of why you should avoid explaining downvotes.  It just results in people insulting you and upvoting the post out of spite.  Hopefully R-Fever learned their lesson about trying to be helpful and explaining to someone why they felt their post wasn't useful rather than staying anonymous.

Comment: What hapenned with the question is just insane... A typo question with a bounty awarded and extremely upvoted answer, all that due to a really bad comment and the reaction of a user.

Comment: R-Fever comment should have been flagged for rude or not constructive, the rest is overreactions in fact

Comment: I don't really get the point of the meta post. You didn't provide this R-Fever comment everyone here is so interested in and seems to think you're talking about; and if you think the question should be closed, why not make your case to that end (maybe in the R chat)? Also, it's not clear what you mean by the R community overreacting. Too many upvotes? The downvote spree? The bounty? All seem pretty humdrum to me and hardly like coordinated or unified behavior.

Comment: @Frank Hi Frank. Nice to hear from R people responding. I cast a close vote on the question but it seemed that I was the only one doing that. I don't know what most people think about votes, but I think votes, as well as bounty, should be used to support posts with good quality. However,  the phenomenon around this post appears to violate this: voting becomes a tool of gaming.

Comment: @Frank What I think to be fair, is 1> flag comments which we think rude or not-constructive; 2> close and down vote the question; 3> definitely don't up-vote the answer, let alone the bounty. However, what really happened is just insane. A typo question, as well as an answer to the typo, gained huge up-votes. Is this the goal of moderation?

Comment: Ok. I don't really find the votes or bounty extreme. I didn't notice this question until your meta post, but the answer is quite good and the votes just reflect that it was brought to a lot of folks' attention, not some sort of bias, I guess. Up and down votes are a tool of moderation, but they're more subjective than close votes, so I wouldn't spend time telling others how to use them. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) Regarding the comments, I still don't know what they looked like, but it looks like they've been handled now (since I don't see them). Close voting seems reasonable here, but leaving it also seems fine, since the answer is good. I'll leave it alone since I don't think it's doing any damage. We could talk in one of the R chat rooms if you want to discuss it further (so I don't clutter your meta post more).

Comment: This question (this one here on meta) is simply incomplete now. The described behavior can't be verified in the original question and there is no evidence shown here.

Comment: @catastrophic-failure My comment above has a direct quote from one of the comments which was still around when I first looked at the question. In another comment, the same user said they would have downvoted the answer if only they were able to afford the cost of a downvote.

Comment: @duplode Hadn't seen it, thanks for the heads up. Nevertheless, it should be in the question itself, otherwise it's still incomplete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First things first - on the question itself, if it's more suitable to be closed due to a typo, then you should cast the first vote.  I can't/won't speak to it since R is about as familiar to me as Assembly would be familiar to my sister's pet dog, but this is the portion in which we entrust you to make the right call.

Second, to the user being targeted with serial votes - the likely scenario is that those votes will be rolled back.  If they aren't, then they can come to Meta, inquire about them, and a moderator can then investigate.

Third, as an outsider looking at the aftermath, I can't see anything that would've given me any impression of anything bad happening.  Without that context it's tough to really weigh in on the crux of your question.  If we had known while the matter was transpiring, perhaps we non-R denizens could weigh in with an opinion.

Comment: *Wow your sisters dog must be a real assembly pro!*

Comment: @Cœur: I'm not seeing a typo...